# Problema de sintaxis

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sintaxis

miren es una de las pocas veces que me encuentro con este problema:

> "Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line
>   1, query was: SELECT `movimientosformatos`.* FROM
>   `movimientosformatos` WHERE (idMovimiento=)"

la consulta es la siguiente:

```
//Elimina los datos del archivo en la base de datos y todas sus relaciones
    public function deleteAll($idFile){

        try {
            $this->getAdapter()->beginTransaction();

            $select   = $this->getAdapter()->select()->from("archivos")->where("idPertenece=?",$idFile);
            $formatos = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);

            if(count($formatos) > 0)
                throw new Exception("No se puede eliminar el documento seleccionado debido a que tiene formatos asignados, antes de eliminar el documento es necesario eliminar los formatos");

            $file = $this->fetchRow("idArchivo={$idFile}");

            if($file["idSalaColaborativa"] != null && $file["idSalaColaborativa"] > 0)
            {
                $select      = $this->getAdapter()->select()->from("movimientos")->where("idSalaColaborativa={$file["idSalaColaborativa"]}");
                $movimientos = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);

                if(count($movimientos) > 0){
                    foreach($movimientos as $movimiento){
                        $this->getAdapter()->delete("movimientosformatos","idMovimiento={$movimiento["idMovimiento"]}");
                    }
                }

                $this->getAdapter()->delete("movimientos", "idSalaColaborativa={$file["idSalaColaborativa"]}");
                $this->getAdapter()->delete("salascolaborativas", "idSalaColaborativa={$file["idSalaColaborativa"]}");
            }

            $this->getAdapter()->delete("bitacoraArchivoUsuario","idArchivo=".$idFile);
            $this->getAdapter()->delete("archivoperfilpermiso","idArchivo=".$idFile);
            $this->getAdapter()->delete("bitacoraLectura","idArchivo=".$idFile);
            $this->getAdapter()->delete("archivos","idArchivo=".$idFile);

            $this->getAdapter()->commit();

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $this->getAdapter()->rollBack();
            throw  new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido Armando, para comodidad de todos te recomiendo que formatee bien el error para darnos mejor lectura, también que agregues las etiquetas faltantes para que tengas más alcance de usuarios.... Date una vuelta por [ask] para más información

Comment: Parece que una variable te llegue vacio y por eso el " WHERE idMovimiento=" te de el error.

Comment: Tienes `idMovimiento` y también `idSalaColaborativa`. Si no me equivoco debería ser: `$idMovimiento` e `$idSalaColaborativa`. Me refiero a esta línea: `"idMovimiento={$movimiento["idMovimiento"]}"`, debería ser: `"idMovimiento={$movimiento["$idMovimiento"]}"` ¿Puedes verificar eso? Saludos